# Select All directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using [Checklist model](http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/) directive with my App. I have issue, if -

- I click select all button though it write up the array but its not
  selecting checkbox. Same issue with Uncheck All though it empty the
  model but it doesn't uncheck checkboxes.
- If I select 2 or 3 randomly checkbox and click Select All Button it doesn't select All check-boxes.

Though its writing values to pushArray. But issues are checking and unchecking checkboxes.

```
$scope.items = [{id:1, name:"abc"},{id:2, name:"def"},{id:3, name:"ghi"}];
$scope.pushArray = [];    
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="e in items">
        <td class="text-right">
        {{e.id}}    
        <input type="checkbox" checklist-change="imChanged()" checklist-model="pushArray" checklist-value="e.id" >             
        </td>            
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are pushing the complete list of object which is wrong. You just need to map the list and pass the `id` to the `$scope`

**Edit:** Works fine when you use `$scope.pushArray` as an object instead of array.

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tnbOovu1dAfS5S6ASswB?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="selection">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="e in items">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="pushArray.ids" checklist-value="e.id"> {{e.name}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  {{pushArray.ids | json}}

  <br />

  <button ng-click="select_all();">Select All</button>
  <button ng-click="unselect_all();">Unselect All</button>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["checklist-model"]);

app.controller('selection', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "abc"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "def"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "ghi"
  }];
  $scope.pushArray = { ids: []}; // Works fine when using it as an object
  //$scope.pushArray = [];

  $scope.select_all = function() {
    $scope.pushArray.ids = $scope.items.map(function(item) { return item.id; });
  };

  $scope.unselect_all = function() {
    $scope.pushArray.ids = [];
  };
}]);
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: THough its works for me, but I am not clear. If I take ` $scope.pushArray ` as array whats wrong with that. You are also doing same with ` $scope.pushArray ` adding array to this object.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the examples on `checklist-model` and fix this issue. Check them out http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/